# Can I use Amazon Kinesis Connectors to send a stream to two destinations (two emitters)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Using the Amazon Kinesis Connectors library, is it possible to configure two Emitters?  For example, I would like to filter and transform records from the stream, then store the result in Redshift using the Redshift emitter, but also send the filtered and transformed records out to a new Kinesis stream.

The IKinesisConnectorPipeline interface only seems designed for a single Emitter, but I would assume that many users are doing multiple things with a single stream so I'm wondering what the standard way to do this is.

Comment: this is more than 6 months old. Any answers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have one Kinesis Application (i.e. a consumer) per pipeline/emitter.

It makes it simple to add new processors, and they each have their own checkpoint.